# Error initializing plugins - GraphDB 8.7.2

Tags: graphdb

I have tried updating my POM from v8.6.1 to v8.7.2 and in the process successfully re-created a sample repo with the new version's preload tool.
Although I have not altered my java code at all (which runs perfectly with v.8.6.1), now I get an error when trying to retrieve the repository from the manager with the following command:

```
repository = repositoryManager.getRepository(repositoryId);
```

The error is the following:

```
197822 [main] INFO  com.ontotext.plugin.magic-predicates  - Registering InverseMagicPredicate: http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ/property#strSplit
197823 [main] INFO  com.ontotext.trree.sdk.impl.PluginManager  - Initializing plugin 'literals-index'
198002 [main] INFO  com.ontotext.plugin.literals-index  - Literals indices restored.
198003 [main] INFO  com.ontotext.trree.sdk.impl.PluginManager  - Initializing plugin 'geospatial'
198009 [main] INFO  com.ontotext.trree.plugin.geo.GeoSpatialPlugin  - Plugin:geospatial initialized
198010 [main] INFO  com.ontotext.trree.sdk.impl.PluginManager  - Initializing plugin 'sparql-mm'
198400 [main] INFO  com.ontotext.graphdb.sparqlmm.FunctionLoader  - Registered 48 functions from package com.github.tkurz.sparqlmm.function.
198400 [main] INFO  com.ontotext.trree.sdk.impl.PluginManager  - Initializing plugin 'dependencies-plugin'
198409 [main] INFO  com.ontotext.trree.sdk.impl.PluginManager  - Initializing plugin 'similarity'
198429 [main] INFO  com.ontotext.trree.sdk.impl.PluginManager  - Initializing plugin 'GeoSPARQL'
231881 [main] INFO  com.ontotext.trree.geosparql.FunctionLoader  - Registered 50 functions from package com.useekm.geosparql.
231882 [main] INFO  com.ontotext.trree.sdk.impl.PluginManager  - Initializing plugin 'lucene-connector'
231896 [main] ERROR com.ontotext.trree.sdk.impl.PluginManager  - Plugin 'lucene-connector' failed to initialize:org/json/simple/parser/ParseException
231897 [main] INFO  com.ontotext.trree.sdk.impl.PluginManager  - Initializing plugin 'rdfrank'
232224 [main] INFO  com.ontotext.trree.sdk.impl.PluginManager  - Initializing plugin 'notifications'
232237 [main] ERROR com.ontotext.trree.free.GraphDBFreeSchemaRepository  - Error initializing plugins:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ontotext.trree.plugin.externalsync.ExternalSyncPlugin.shutdown(ExternalSyncPlugin.java:803)
    at com.ontotext.trree.sdk.PluginBase.shutdown(PluginBase.java:100)
    at com.ontotext.trree.sdk.impl.PluginManager.disablePluginInt(PluginManager.java:986)
    at com.ontotext.trree.sdk.impl.PluginManager.removePlugin(PluginManager.java:361)
    at com.ontotext.trree.sdk.impl.PluginManager.initialize(PluginManager.java:128)
    at com.ontotext.trree.OwlimSchemaRepository.initPlugins(OwlimSchemaRepository.java:1979)
    at com.ontotext.trree.OwlimSchemaRepository.initializeInternal(OwlimSchemaRepository.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.sail.helpers.AbstractSail.initialize(AbstractSail.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.sail.SailRepository.initializeInternal(SailRepository.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.base.AbstractRepository.initialize(AbstractRepository.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.manager.LocalRepositoryManager.createRepository(LocalRepositoryManager.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.manager.RepositoryManager.getRepository(RepositoryManager.java:424)
```

I have specified the -Dregister-external-plugins=.... in the VM Options.

Any ideas what might be wrong? Should I go for a previous version and if so, which one?

Thanks

Comment: Which external plugins are you using and what are their versions?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an incompatible Lucene connector configuration. I recommend deleting the Lucene connector directory and once the repository starts you can recreate the connector(s). The Lucene connector directory is located in the repository's data directory: <graphdb-data-dir>/repositories/<repository-id>/storage/lucene-connector. The easiest way to find <graphdb-data-dir> is looking at the startup messages of GraphDB where it will print something like:

GraphDB Data directory: /opt/test/graphdb-free-8.7.2/data

As Konstantin mentioned the problem might also have to do with register-external-plugins.